# How to detect empty selection on <input type="file"/> in React?

Tags: file, reactjs, input, components

I have a component which uses `<input type="file" value="" onChange={(e) => callback(e.target.files}/>` to get user selected files. But if user cancels the file selection popup, the callback will never be called since there is no change. This is nonsense, since the expected action is callback gets called with null or empty array.

But how to implement this? I didn't find any related event to listen.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong but if a user canceled the file selection then no change has been made to the value of the input, hence no need to invoke the callback

Comment: @Sag1v hi, the first part of your analysis is right, but the there is indeed the need to invoke the callback. e.g, if we try to make a async confirm function, the callback should always be called even if user click cancel, since cancel also means some result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var godzilla = document.getElementById('godzilla')

godzilla.onclick = charge

function charge()
{
    document.body.onfocus = roar
    console.log('chargin')
}
    
function roar()
{
    if(godzilla.files.length) alert('ROAR! FILES!')
    else alert('*empty wheeze*')
    document.body.onfocus = null
    console.log('depleted')
}
//source on findle http://jsfiddle.net/Shiboe/yuK3r/6/
```

```html
<input type='file' id='godzilla' style='display:none' />
<button onclick='document.getElementById("godzilla").click()'>mech-godzilla</button>
```